# backport-iwlwifi-dkms broke my wifi

Tags: wifi, system, appcenter, drivers

I rebooted and found that not only did I not have a wifi connection, but the System Settings Network panel had lost its Hotspot and WiFi tabs (only VPN & Proxy)! When I checked the AppCenter Installed tab, I found at the very top of the list was a backport-iwlwifi-dkms package that I don't recall ever installing. Upon removing it and rebooting, things were back to normal, although the AppCenter Installed tab continues to show a Drivers section with the backport-iwlwifi-dkms package ready to be installed (which I obviously don't want to do!).

Does anybody know what is going on? And how can I get this horrible driver out of my Installed list?

Comment: I see it too and almost installed it (it asked for secureboot password, so I cancelled it - if it ain't broke..), I think it's just an update, that's why you will see it there. Good to know that uninstalling is so simple though..

Answer (score 1):

I would just ignore it. I also get old(er) nvidia drivers being offered, but I just don't even pay attention to them:

[image]

Comment: IMHO, the people at Elementary really should not put things up on their AppCenter that break their clients' systems!

Comment: I don't think this is really their fault. First of all, it's backport by Intel pushed to Ubuntu repository ([as some people may even need it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046589/backport-for-iwlwifi)). Second, it's separate from normal updates - I had to specifically click it's button to install it, it was always excluded from normal updates. I'm actually surprised how well this is handled.

Comment: I thought the whole point of a separate Elementary AppCenter was to give the Elementary developers control of their users' systems, saving them having to get into the complexities of handling a vanilla Ubuntu system. That's certainly why I decided to go with Elementary anyway. Furthermore this driver is showing up in my "Installed" tab, even though it's NOT currently installed, and inviting me to install it. Finally I don't know how it ever got installed in the first place; it was sheer luck that i thought to try uninstalling it when I suddenly found my WiFi had been wrecked.

Comment: After "sudo apt install -y linux-firmware", I got the message "linux-firmware is already the newest version (1.173.18)." Does this mean I didn't need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove iwlwifi driver from App Center.
Then open terminal and type:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Provide the result of this command.
I will be able to guide you which firmware for Wi-Fi adapter is needed.

Comment: I can see no option to in the App Center to remove the driver (or I would've done it already and never have submitted this post!). As it stands my WiFi works most of the time without the driver anyway. It does go down every few days and I have to switch the WiFi off and on to get it back up. If a new driver will fix that minor nuisance I'll try it, otherwise I can live with things the way they are.

Comment: Here's the output you asked for: sudo update-initramfs -u
[sudo] password for tfhavel:         
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-59-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p6
I: (UUID=1b076493-99fa-4aa7-bfb2-81d480f67e0e)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.

Comment: I thought it will show the information about missing firmware. sudo lscpi will list all devices. I am curious what kind of Wi-Fi adapter it is.

Comment: lspci (not lscpi, which doesn't exist) does not show any wifi device; ifconfig shows however the device name is wlp0s20f3, if that means anything to you. The laptop itself is an LG Gram-17Z990-R-AAS9U1.

Comment: wlp0s20f3 is the interface name what does says nothing about the Wi-Fi adapter model. I will try to find out using the name of the laptop model.

Comment: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html

Comment: Intel Wireless-AC 9560. Above I provided a link. Download tar.gz file for this model and unzip. I will check later what is inside and provide the guide how to install it

Comment: Tutorial for the  installation of the iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode added.

Comment: Added where? I see no link to a tutorial in your comment.

Comment: OK, I found your tutorial in my Stackexchange Inbox. It seems to say I need this driver for my WiFi to "operate" whereas it works ok most of the time. Can you give me a firm (no pun intended) reason why I should install it nonetheless?

Comment: Tutorial is here in this thread. The reason is that usually Linux by default does not install the Wi-Fi driver. Linux as you probably know was invented as a system for servers. It is based on minix. It does not work out of the box like Windows. Of course some developer teams created distribitions which suport some default wireless adapters, however newer laptops are not supported by default and sometimes people have to wait few years for wireless adapter driver implementation. That is why we check what is the model of the adapter and if firmware exists we install it manually.

Comment: There is already a ucode file with that name in /lib/firmware. Its size is 2678284 bytes, while the one I just downloaded is 2677620 bytes. I'm creating a backup of the one in /lib/firmware, just in case …

Comment: In fact there are a bunch of files in /lib/firmware which are apparently different versions of the driver, with names shell matching the following pattern: iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-{33,34,38,41,43,46}.ucode. There is another set matching iwlwifi-9260-pu-b0-jf-b0-{33,34,38,41,43,46}.ucode. Indeed there are a total of 85 (!) files in /lib/firmware matching iwlwifi*ucode. Seems strange I only have to replace one of them?

Comment: Yes. Make a backup of this file and then replace it. But I will not guarantee  it will solve your problem permanently.

Comment: After "sudo apt install -y linux-firmware" it said "linux-firmware is already the newest version (1.173.18)". Also, after "sudo apt install -y linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)" it said "linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-59-generic is already the newest version (5.3.0-59.53~18.04.1)".

Comment: Also, after "sudo update-initramfs -u" it complained about the following missing firmware: /lib/firmware/i915/{tgl_dmc_ver2_04,skl_guc_33.0.0,btx_guc_33.0.0,kbl_guc_33.0.0,glk_guc_33.0.0,kbl_guc_33.0.0,icl_guc_33.0.0.bin (yes, it complained twice about the "kbl" one), then said it would attempt to resume.

Comment: Finished, rebooted, and the wifi seems to work at least as well as it did -:)

Comment: I will provide solution how to install firmware for Intel i915.

Comment: Tutorial provided in this thread below.

Answer (score 0):

Type commands in terminal one by one:

```
cd
cd /Downloads
wget https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.618819.0.tgz
tar -xzvf iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.618819.0.tgz 
cd iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.618819.0
sudo cp iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode /lib/firmware
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-generic
sudo apt install -y linux-firmware 
sudo apt install -y linux-image-extra-*
sudo apt install -y linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo apt autoremove 
sudo apt autoclean
sudo reboot
```

Explanation from the README.iwlwifi-9000.ucode

> 1. OVERVIEW

> The files iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode provided in this package
> must be present on your system in order for the Intel Wireless WiFi Link
> AGN driver for Linux (iwlwifi) to operate on your system.

> The "-34" in the filename reflects an interface/architecture version number.
> It will change only when changes in new uCode releases make the new uCode
> incompatible with earlier drivers.

> On adapter initialization, and at varying times during the uptime of
> the adapter, the microcode is loaded into the memory on the network
> adapter.  The microcode provides the low level MAC features including
> radio control and high precision timing events (backoff, transmit,
> etc.) while also providing varying levels of packet filtering which can
> be used to keep the host from having to handle packets that are not of
> interest given the current operating mode of the device.

> 2. INSTALLATION

> The iwlwifi driver will look for the file iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode
> using the kernel's firmware_class infrastructure.
> More information can be found under Documentation/firmware_class in kernel
> source. In order to function correctly, you need to have this support enabled
> in your kernel.  When you configure the kernel, you can find this option in
> the following location:

```
    Device Drivers ->
            Generic Driver Options ->
                    Userspace firmware loading support
```

> You can determine if your kernel currently has firmware loader support
> by looking for the CONFIG_FW_LOADER definition on your kernel's
> .config.

> In addition to having the firmware_class support in your kernel, you
> must also have a working udev and uevent infrastructure configured.
> The steps for installing and configuring udev are very
> distribution specific.

> Once you have the firmware loader in place (or if you aren't sure and
> you just want to try things to see if it works), you need to install
> the microcode file into the appropriate location.

> Where that appropriate location is depends (again) on your system
> distribution.  You can typically find this location by looking in the
> udev scripts of your distro, the default is /lib/firmware.

> Installation of the firmware is simply:

```
    % cp iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode /lib/firmware
```

> You can now load the driver (see the INSTALL and README.iwlwifi provided with the iwlwifi package for information on building and using that driver.)

Additional Intel Wi-Fi Linux Drivers for other people: [Intel Wi-Fi drivers for Linux:](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html)

Answer (score 0):

How to install i915 firmware.

Type in terminal:

```
cd /home/username/Downloads/
sudo mkdir i915
cd i915 
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git 
sudo cp -R linux-firmware/i915/* /lib/firmware/i915/
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot
```

Comment: OK (except for the "/" at the beginning of "/linux-firmware" on the cp line).

Comment: Corrected. You were right. Let me know how Wi-Fi works. The same way as before or it is stable now?

Comment: Having now used it for a month, yes it does appear more stable now! Thanks, Tim